# How to lookup hostname / ip address as seen from the outside?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, docker

I use docker with drone for my continuous integration jobs and all local queries about the job's ip address and hostname are a lie because docking is rewriting everything.

I'd really like to know which box a job is running on when the job begins, and the only way I can think to do this is to query an external service that does an IP lookup of the origin and (optionally) resolves to a hostname (my jobs are trusted, so they have access to the interwebz to resolve their dependencies).

Is there a command line tool (available for Debian) that would be able to resolve the hostname of the machine they are running on by using an external service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple HTTP "echo" server. There are some already available:

```
$ curl http://httpbin.org/ip
```

This returns a json structure containing your ip:

```
{
  "origin": "10.20.30.40"
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a rate limit involved; check before you use the service. Or write your own.

Comment: `host `curl http://httpbin.org/ip | jq -r '.origin'``

Comment: why did somebody downvote this?